# Can you put adverbs at the start of a sentence in French?

Tags: grammaire, ordre-des-mots, adverbes

Is it grammatically correct to use an adverb at the start of a sentence in French like in English? Like in the sentences

> Seriously, stop it!
>
> Really?

Or any sentence that uses an adverb like that.

Answer (score 4):

Évidemment, quelle question ! :)

(Obviously, why the question!)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it.
Maybe this link will help you (if you understand French) 
http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect6&info0=6.1.17

Comment: A small summary of the link would greatly enhance this answer, IMO

Answer (score 1):

**Quand on utilise un adverbe avec un verbe (dans une phrase construite), l'ordre a une importance:**

**Oui, pour les adverbes communs** (qui ont un sens précis, notamment).

**Non** (en tous cas, cela ne se dit pas), pour des adverbes spéciaux ou généraux, comme: *beaucoup, trop, moins*. Ceux-ci ne s'utilisent qu'après le verbe: *Je l'aime beaucoup, je l'aime trop, je l'aime moins.*.

**Rarement**, pour certains adverbes: *encore* (au contraire, *souvent* peut se trouver en tête de phrase).

**Quand on utilise un adverbe seul ou sans verbe, on peut le mettre n'importe où, c'est possible pour n'importe quel adverbe.**

Comment: Aimes-tu les pâtes ? Beaucoup oui ! Et le riz ? Moins. Petit échange prouvant qu'on peut très bien commencer par ces mots.

Comment: @LaurentS. remarque judicieuse, quand il n'y a pas de verbe. J'ai précisé ma réponse.